# jqGrid export data AJAX

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I am trying to export all of the data from a grid. I wrote a function that does all of the exporting to excel. I just need to get the data from the grid.

I have it working using:

```
$("#grid").jqGrid('excelExport',{"url":"gridExport.php"});
```

I have a jquery click function that runs that and it works but it redirects the gridExport.php. I am trying to get this to open without moving the page.

I tried to just write my own jquery post function to the gridExport.php but I am not getting all of the params I need from the grid. I am assuming I can manually grab all the params I need and send them to the gridExport.php but I am not 100% how to do that and/or if there is an easier way to do it.

Any help on this would be great.

Thanks!

**UPDATE:**

I figured out a way to make this work. I just used my own jquery post function and got the paramas I needed from the grid and passed it to my processing page via the post function. I just needed the postData and colModel form my grid. This is how I got the params and put them into JS variables:

```
        var gParam = $("#grid").jqGrid('getGridParam','postData');
        var gParamCol = $("#grid").jqGrid('getGridParam','colModel');
```

Comment: It's important to know the `datatype` of jqGrid which you use. Do you have `"local"` value of `datatype` or you load the data from the server? Is current filter of the grid is important for the export? You wrote "I am not getting all of the params". What you really need to "export"? Do you need to export the state of the grid to be able to show the grid which looks like the current one? On the other side you wrote about "exporting to excel". How you plan to export to excel jqGrid parameters?

Comment: Thanks for the help @Oleg. I figured it out yesterday. I just did my own post and extracted the params I needed from the grid. I will update the question. Thanks!

Comment: You are welcome! If you need get many options of jqGrid you can use `getGridParam` without any parameter `var options = $("#grid").jqGrid("getGridParam");`. It will return you the reference to *all* parameters of jqGrid. So you can use later `options.colModel`, `options.colNames`, `options.postData.filters` and so on. It could simplify your code.

Comment: Yeah I saw that but I decided to just pull out those 2 (postData and colModel) because that's all I needed. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

I figured out a way to make this work. I just used my own jquery post function and got the paramas I needed from the grid and passed it to my processing page via the post function. I just needed the postData and colModel form my grid. This is how I got the params and put them into JS variables:

```
    var gParam = $("#grid").jqGrid('getGridParam','postData');
    var gParamCol = $("#grid").jqGrid('getGridParam','colModel');
```